# motion planning with kinect

Tags: ros, motion-planning, kinect, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I would like to generate plans for my robot with rviz using the kinect for environment representation. Can somebody mention the necessary steps in order to do that? Up to now I have set up my urdf with the kinect in it, I visualize pointclouds in rviz but when I ask for a plan, the robot joints move through the pointcloud image. I have created the config files according to tutorials, any ideas and suggestions are welcome, thank you in advance for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199360/motion-planning-with-kinect/) by [bridos](https://answers.ros.org/users/18758/bridos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you are using MoveIt (Not because I'm good at guessing, but because that's the only one I know the answer for)

In case you are using MoveIt, you need to set up the Kinect the way described in this [tutorial](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/3D_Sensors). This will generate an octomap, representing your obstacles.

In case you are using another framework for motion planning, you should say which one, since the answer depends on that fact

---

Originally posted by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) with karma: 683 on 2014-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-12-15**:
@bridos said: Hello, thank you for your reply. Yes I am using Moveit. I have set up the files according to the tutorial. Is there anything else that needs to be done? Like remapping incoming clouds from one topic to another (as I have seen in other tutorials) or should rviz be good to go?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-12-15**:
@bridos, please use comments, not answers, to iterate with other people.

**Comment by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on 2014-12-16**:
Depends on your setup. You can tell MoveIt the topic of your PointCloud in the `sensors_rgbd.yaml` file under `point_cloud_topic: [your_point_cloud_topic]`. It's important that you have transformations available to your camera lens, otherwise nothing will show up.

**Comment by [bridos](https://answers.ros.org/users/18758/bridos/) on 2015-03-03**:
Hello again, I have things showing up on RVIZ from the camera, but the robot ignores them and moves right through them, it doesn't recognise that as a collision environment